# How can I make this function more efficient? - Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance

Desperate to find out how I can make my function more efficient. This is what I have now

```
public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends T> c) {
    for (T x : c)
        add(i++, x);
    return true;
}

public void add(int i, T x) {
    if (n + 1 > a.length) resize();
    System.arraycopy(a, i, a, i+1, n-i);
    a[i] = x;
    n++;
}

protected void resize() {
    T[] b = f.newArray(Math.max(2 * n,1));
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, n);
    a = b;
}
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to implement a more efficient way to use my addAll function. Any tips or pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What evidence do you have that this code is inefficient at all?

Comment: Prof's efficiency submission server saying that it is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your `addAll` method is inefficient: chances are, it would resize the underlying collection several times before completing.

You can eliminate the unnecessary resizing by taking the size of the collection being added in `addAll`, resizing to fit all its elements, and then proceeding with copying.

One way to implement this would be adding a resizing method that takes the new size:

```
protected void resizeTo(int newSize)
```

your `resize()` method would then be covered by a call of `resizeTo`

```
protected void resize() {
    resizeTo(Math.max(2 * n,1));
}
```

Comment: My resize function already resizes the array by (Math.max(2 * n,1)) though. Unless I'm overseeing something

Comment: @johnnyboyyy I mean, the `addAll` method should be resizing to `n+c.size()` before proceeding with the loop.